# Windows Ganache install Errors

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache, ganache-cli

I'm attempting to install ganache via `npm install ganache` from my windows machine using PowerShell.

Upon execution, a list of errors is populated.

One asked me to install python which I thought was strange but did so.
Another asked me to install Visual Studio which I did but that error still shows up along with a slew of other errors.
Can I get some assistance with what I'm doing wrong?

I'll attach the errors and the log info

```
PS C:\Users\Samson> npm install ganache --global
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32407.337) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-15T23_02_35_045Z-debug-0.log
```

Log:

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.7.0
2 info using node@v16.14.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Samson\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:validate Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load Completed in 10ms
18 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 11ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm install ganache
22 verbose argv "install" "ganache" "--global"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
24 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 4ms
25 timing npm:load:display Completed in 7ms
26 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs
27 verbose logfile C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-15T23_02_35_045Z-debug-0.log
28 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 14ms
29 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
31 timing npm:load Completed in 35ms
32 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
33 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
34 timing idealTree:init Completed in 8ms
35 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 3ms
36 silly idealTree buildDeps
37 silly fetch manifest ganache@*
38 silly logfile done cleaning log files
39 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/ganache 459ms (cache revalidated)
40 silly placeDep ROOT ganache@7.0.4 OK for:  want: *
41 silly fetch manifest @trufflesuite/bigint-buffer@1.1.9
42 silly fetch manifest emittery@0.10.0
43 silly fetch manifest keccak@3.0.1
44 silly fetch manifest leveldown@6.1.0
45 silly fetch manifest secp256k1@4.0.2
46 silly fetch manifest bufferutil@4.0.5
47 silly fetch manifest utf-8-validate@5.0.7
48 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/secp256k1 48ms (cache revalidated)
49 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/leveldown 85ms (cache revalidated)
50 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/emittery 93ms (cache revalidated)
51 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bufferutil 97ms (cache revalidated)
52 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/utf-8-validate 101ms (cache revalidated)
53 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@trufflesuite%2fbigint-buffer 174ms (cache revalidated)
54 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/keccak 428ms (cache revalidated)
55 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 904ms
56 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 906ms
57 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
58 timing idealTree Completed in 919ms
59 timing reify:loadTrees Completed in 956ms
60 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 4ms
61 silly reify mark retired [
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache',
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache',
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache.cmd',
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache.ps1',
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache-cli',
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache-cli.cmd',
61 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache-cli.ps1'
61 silly reify ]
62 silly reify moves {
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.ganache-X4EVJ954',
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\.ganache-ApnXwpxU',
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache.cmd': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\.ganache.cmd-0AfD9RUj',
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache.ps1': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\.ganache.ps1-s4Tplx4t',
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache-cli': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\.ganache-cli-KXLzODm1',
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache-cli.cmd': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\.ganache-cli.cmd-ewaTnCIQ',
62 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\ganache-cli.ps1': 'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\.ganache-cli.ps1-VeJmK9lJ'
62 silly reify }
63 timing reify:retireShallow Completed in 12ms
64 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 1ms
65 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache Completed in 949ms
66 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
67 timing reify:diffTrees Completed in 3ms
68 timing reify:createSparse Completed in 17ms
69 timing reify:loadShrinkwraps Completed in 994ms
70 timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
71 silly audit bulk request {
71 silly audit   ganache: [ '7.0.4' ],
71 silly audit   '@trufflesuite/bigint-buffer': [ '1.1.9' ],
71 silly audit   'base64-js': [ '1.5.1' ],
71 silly audit   'bn.js': [ '4.12.0' ],
71 silly audit   brorand: [ '1.1.0' ],
71 silly audit   buffer: [ '6.0.3' ],
71 silly audit   bufferutil: [ '4.0.5' ],
71 silly audit   catering: [ '2.1.0' ],
71 silly audit   elliptic: [ '6.5.4' ],
71 silly audit   emittery: [ '0.10.0' ],
71 silly audit   'hash.js': [ '1.1.7' ],
71 silly audit   'hmac-drbg': [ '1.0.1' ],
71 silly audit   ieee754: [ '1.2.1' ],
71 silly audit   inherits: [ '2.0.4' ],
71 silly audit   'is-buffer': [ '2.0.5' ],
71 silly audit   keccak: [ '3.0.1' ],
71 silly audit   leveldown: [ '6.1.0' ],
71 silly audit   'abstract-leveldown': [ '7.2.0' ],
71 silly audit   'level-concat-iterator': [ '3.1.0' ],
71 silly audit   'level-supports': [ '2.1.0' ],
71 silly audit   'minimalistic-assert': [ '1.0.1' ],
71 silly audit   'minimalistic-crypto-utils': [ '1.0.1' ],
71 silly audit   'napi-macros': [ '2.0.0' ],
71 silly audit   'node-addon-api': [ '2.0.2' ],
71 silly audit   'node-gyp-build': [ '4.3.0' ],
71 silly audit   'queue-microtask': [ '1.2.3' ],
71 silly audit   'queue-tick': [ '1.0.0' ],
71 silly audit   secp256k1: [ '4.0.2' ],
71 silly audit   'utf-8-validate': [ '5.0.7' ]
71 silly audit }
72 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 153ms
73 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 155ms
74 silly audit report {}
75 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
76 timing reify:audit Completed in 156ms
77 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/minimalistic-assert Completed in 180ms
78 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/queue-microtask Completed in 188ms
79 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/ieee754 Completed in 187ms
80 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/inherits Completed in 187ms
81 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/is-buffer Completed in 188ms
82 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/catering Completed in 187ms
83 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/emittery Completed in 189ms
84 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/brorand Completed in 190ms
85 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/leveldown/node_modules/level-concat-iterator Completed in 194ms
86 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/bn.js Completed in 193ms
87 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/base64-js Completed in 193ms
88 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/minimalistic-crypto-utils Completed in 196ms
89 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/queue-tick Completed in 201ms
90 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/node-gyp-build Completed in 201ms
91 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/buffer Completed in 200ms
92 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/hmac-drbg Completed in 203ms
93 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/napi-macros Completed in 209ms
94 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/leveldown/node_modules/level-supports Completed in 209ms
95 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/hash.js Completed in 242ms
96 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/utf-8-validate Completed in 245ms
97 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/elliptic Completed in 245ms
98 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/bufferutil Completed in 245ms
99 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/@trufflesuite/bigint-buffer Completed in 267ms
100 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/leveldown/node_modules/abstract-leveldown Completed in 285ms
101 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/keccak Completed in 307ms
102 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/node-addon-api Completed in 349ms
103 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/secp256k1 Completed in 427ms
104 timing reifyNode:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/leveldown Completed in 629ms
105 timing reify:unpack Completed in 630ms
106 timing reify:unretire Completed in 0ms
107 timing build:queue Completed in 2ms
108 timing build:link:node_modules/ganache Completed in 7ms
109 timing build:link Completed in 7ms
110 info run @trufflesuite/bigint-buffer@1.1.9 install node_modules/ganache/node_modules/@trufflesuite/bigint-buffer node-gyp rebuild
111 info run bufferutil@4.0.5 install node_modules/ganache/node_modules/bufferutil node-gyp rebuild
112 info run keccak@3.0.1 install node_modules/ganache/node_modules/keccak node-gyp rebuild
113 info run leveldown@6.1.0 install node_modules/ganache/node_modules/leveldown node-gyp rebuild
114 info run secp256k1@4.0.2 install node_modules/ganache/node_modules/secp256k1 node-gyp rebuild
115 info run utf-8-validate@5.0.7 install node_modules/ganache/node_modules/utf-8-validate node-gyp rebuild
116 info run bufferutil@4.0.5 install { code: 1, signal: null }
117 verbose reify failed optional dependency C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\bufferutil
118 silly reify mark deleted [
118 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\bufferutil'
118 silly reify ]
119 timing build:run:install:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/bufferutil Completed in 2395ms
120 info run keccak@3.0.1 install { code: 1, signal: null }
121 info run leveldown@6.1.0 install { code: 1, signal: null }
122 info run secp256k1@4.0.2 install { code: 1, signal: null }
123 info run utf-8-validate@5.0.7 install { code: 1, signal: null }
124 verbose reify failed optional dependency C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\utf-8-validate
125 silly reify mark deleted [
125 silly reify   'C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ganache\\node_modules\\utf-8-validate'
125 silly reify ]
126 timing build:run:install:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/utf-8-validate Completed in 2406ms
127 info run @trufflesuite/bigint-buffer@1.1.9 install { code: 1, signal: null }
128 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 372ms
129 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 8ms
130 timing command:install Completed in 5420ms
131 verbose stack Error: command failed
131 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
131 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
131 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
131 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
132 verbose pkgid keccak@3.0.1
133 verbose cwd C:\Users\Samson
134 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
135 verbose node v16.14.2
136 verbose npm  v8.7.0
137 error code 1
138 error path C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak
139 error command failed
140 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
141 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
141 error gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
141 error gyp info using node@16.14.2 | win32 | x64
141 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
141 error gyp ERR! find VS 
141 error gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
141 error gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
141 error gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32407.337) found at:
141 error gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
141 error gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
141 error gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
141 error gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
141 error gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
141 error gyp ERR! find VS - not found
141 error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
141 error gyp ERR! find VS 
141 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
141 error gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
141 error gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
141 error gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
141 error gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
141 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
141 error gyp ERR! find VS 
141 error gyp ERR! configure error 
141 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
141 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
141 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
141 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Samson\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
141 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\keccak
141 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.14.2
141 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
141 error gyp ERR! not ok
142 verbose exit 1
143 timing npm Completed in 5659ms
144 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1650063755257
145 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1650063757868
146 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1650063757868
147 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1650063757869
148 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1650063757878
149 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/@trufflesuite/bigint-buffer 1650063757878
150 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/keccak 1650063757899
151 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/leveldown 1650063757907
152 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/ganache/node_modules/secp256k1 1650063757920
153 verbose code 1
154 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
154 error     C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-15T23_02_35_045Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: There's a very clear message in the logs *You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio including the "Desktop development with C++" workload. For more information consult the documentation at: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install **Visual Studio 2022 Installer**
2. Enable **Desktop Development with C++**